# Find the numerical value of T (nearest hundreth)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$3^{2T}+5 =2$$

I cannot figure out how to find the numerical value of T and I cannot find any tips on the web.

Comment: Would you please format the mathematical expression in your question using Mathjax. See below,
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164

Comment: @Sophia Is my edit correct?

Comment: Your equation is ambiguous. Is the $T$ in the exponent? If so, you should use parentheses like `3^(2T)+5=2` due to order of operations. Or, much better, use MathJax, like $3^{2T}+5=2$. Is that what you meant? Or did you mean $3^2\cdot T+5=2$?

Answer (score 2):

Can a power of $3$ be a negative number?  Not unless you allow complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is $3^2T +5=2$ then it's relatively easy and we get $T=\frac{-1}{3}$, but mostly $T$ is in the power as @Sophia couldn't solve it and as @RobertIsrael put forth, $T$ becomes a complex number if in the power.